# `normal` does not seem to allow automatic indentation

Tags: vimscript, indentation, normal-mode

Why does this not work as expected?

```
function! MyO()
     normal! o
endfunction
nnoremap TT :call MyO()<cr>i
```

If this is the situation:

```
 |   an indented text
 ^ (normal mode)
```

typing `o` gives:

```
    an indented text
    |
    ^ (insert mode)
```

but typing `TT` gives:

```
    an indented text
|
^ (insert mode)
```

Why can't I enjoy automatic indentation with `normal` ?

Comment: Why `execute "normal! o"` and not `normal! o`?

Comment: @romainl Just a habit as it allows use of special characters (see `:help normal` and answer below).

Comment: Well it's useless here, you might as well make your script simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in `help :normal`, if an argument to `:normal` is not a complete normal-mode command, it will be aborted as if `<Esc>` or `Ctrl-C` was typed. "This implies that an insert command [such as `o`] must be completed (to start Insert mode, see `:startinsert`)."

So your `TT` command is effectively executing `o<esc>i`, which is not the same as just typing `o`--it removes the indent.

To do what you want to do, try the following.

```
execute "normal o\<Space>\<BS>\<Esc>"
startinsert!
```

That opens a new line with the cursor at the indented position, inserts a space and backspaces over the space to preserve the indent, then escapes back to normal mode. The `:startinsert!` command then puts you in insert mode after the indent.